# Utilizing javascript hover on ASP content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having some issues regarding getting some code to work for a project at work. The end goal is to make it so that when the client mouseovers a small image I have on the page, they can see the thumbnail of the image related to that row. Currently this is how I have the code set:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        #full{position:absolute;display:none;}
    </style>
    <asp:Content ID="Full" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
        <asp:Image runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="FullImg"/>
    </asp:Content>
```

The idea here is that this SHOULD create the CSS needed for the image, and create the overlaying div. I could be wrong, my background is in PHP, not ASP. If I try to put the head content above Content1, I receive a "Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls. "Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls." error.

The Javascript placed directly below the above:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    <!-- 
        $('img').hover(function(e){
        var x = e.clientX,
            y = e.clientY;
        $('#FullImg')[0].src = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#FullImg').css({top: y, left : x}).show();
    }, function(){
        $('#FullImg').hide();
        })
    // -->
    </script>
```

Image setup:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Thumbnail" ItemStyle-CssClass="c">
    <ItemTemplate>              
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/ConvertImage.ashx?FleetID=" + m_oUserInfo.CurrentFleetID + "&VehicleID={0}&picID={1}&picType=PictureFull&extention={2}", Eval("VehicleID"), Eval("StoredPictureID"), Eval("PictureExtension"))%>' Target="_blank">
            <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageURL="~/Images/imgHover.png" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

As I said, my background is in PHP, so this ASP transition has been sort of been like drinking from a fire hose. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Updated the code, it still seems to not do anything.

To clarify, this is code I did in [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Trasiva/BaDCe/52/) that works fine with html, but for some reason it won't work in ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your `<asp:Image>` and give it an ID:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        #full{position:absolute;display:none;}
    </style>
    <asp:Content ID="Full" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
        <asp:Image runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="FullImg"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Then adjust your code:

```
<script>
$('img').hover(function(e){
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    $('#FullImg')[0].src = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#FullImg').css({top: y, left : x}).show();
}, function(){
    $('#FullImg').hide();
})
</script>
```

---

### Explanation:

First of all, a `asp:Content` tag does not render it's ID on the client side, which means you can't access it in javascript / css.

Further ASP.Net overwrites the clientside ID's by default to prevent duplicate ID's. However you can overwrite this behavior by adding the attribute `ClientIDMode="Static"`. This will cause the ASP.Net engine to create the clientside tag with the same ID as you have specified it on the server side (in your ASP.Net code) so you can access it with javascript / css more easily.

---

### 2nd way to do it

You can access the ClientID of your img tag and populate it into javascript using ASP.Net inline codes:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    <!-- 
        $('img').hover(function(e){
        var x = e.clientX,
            y = e.clientY;
        $('#<%= FullImg.ClientID %>')[0].src = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#<%= FullImg.ClientID %>').css({top: y, left : x}).show();
    }, function(){
        $('#<%= FullImg.ClientID %>').hide();
        })
    // -->
    </script>
```

Comment: You can always evaluate the id's instead of making them static. Especially if in a repeated control: $('#<%= control.ClientID %>)

Comment: @Newyork167 true, but this solution is easier to understand in my opinion

Comment: @RonnonDex I attempted to implement your code changes, but hovering over the image fails to produce anything on mouseover. Am I perhaps still missing something?

Comment: @Trasiva check the source of the html in your browser and check if the image "FullImg" is beeing created and has the correct id. If that is the case then your issue must lay in something else (javascript, ...)

Comment: @RononDex Despite playing with setting the ClientIDMode to various things, I'm still getting <img id="ctl00_Main_FullImg" clientidmode="Static" src="" style="border-width:0px;">. The internet is not giving me much help on this front either.

Comment: @Trasiva You have to write ClientIDMode. It is case sensitive

Comment: @Trasiva You can try another approach then, check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Few things comes to my mind:
- where is "full" in HTML? If it's rendered  then it's Full, not full.
- it's advisable to apply ID to an image. However, if it's in a class or something .NET usually renders that ID differently than you named it so "imgSomething" can become "thisandthat_imgSomething"; therefore you should use <%= imgSomething.ClientID %> in JS/jQuery when referring to that element.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: No, it was not critique, sorry if I was misunderstood. It was suggesting some possible solutions: I suggested him to use "full" instead of "Full". I also suggested him to apply ID and to fetch that client ID by using ClientID property.

Comment: That comment was auto-generated.  It is simply the closest thing that matched when your answer appeared in the lqp queue.  When you write '...comes to my mind...', it invites conjecture and there is no confidence that you have provided a high quality answer as an absolute assertion.  On the top right of this page under 'Help' there is a link to 'Meta' where you can ask the higher-ups to see if I made the right call or not.   If not, they will fix it.